# How can I remove text strings in a column of google response sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with Google Docs to collect session's data from users but there's a problem:in the response sheet I want to remove a text string.For greater clearity I would like to show you in a Image: I underlined the text i'd like to remove in the response sheet[image]
When a user fills the form, in the responses sheet appears of course the same result as:->Posti Rimanenti[image]
but I would like It appers only the name I'don't need anymore the text previously underlined.
How can I solve this problem?
I tried using a IF formula with SUBSTITUTE function but actually is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
= index(SPLIT(C11,"->"),0,1)
```

This will give you text before "->"

Comment: Thanks now I will try i didn't know the existence of SPLIT